# Is there a named routes and default params equivalent for Razor Pages page routes?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a `JobPosts/Index` page with multiple GET parameter bindings to allow filtering: let's take `CityId` and `IsRemote` for example. I don't want these to be passed as query string parameters, instead I want to use friendly routes for them. So I have defined these:

```
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/JobPosts/Index", "cities/{cityId}/jobs");
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/JobPosts/Index", "remote-jobs");
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/JobPosts/Index", "jobs");
```

The routes work just fine when I type them in the browser and the `CityId` one is bound properly, but two things are missing.

First, there is no way to specify a default value for my `IsRemote` param, which I want to set to `true` *ONLY* when using the `remote-jobs` URL.

And second, when trying to generate a URL like this:

```
<a asp-area="" asp-page="/JobPosts/Index" asp-route-cityId="@Model.CityId"></a>
```

I get the following URL:

```
https://localhost:44391/jobs?cityId=2265885
```

When what I actually expect is:

```
https://localhost:44391/cities/2265885/jobs
```

So it looks like the tag helper or the part responsible for constructing the URL doesn't look at all at the different routes to try and get a best match based on the list of parameters. Actually, it will always use the last page route defined for that page.

Nor do I have the option anywhere to specify a route name for the page route and then use `asp-route` to explicitly say which route I want.

Any ideas how to achieve that? Or if it's something that's on the roadmap for Razor Pages?

*EDIT:* Hardcoding the `href` is not an option. I want this to go through the proper routing services as there are other things to be done as well, like generating culture-specific URL for non-english users (eg. `{cultureId}/cities/{cityId}/jobs` - this is done through route conventions. Hardcoding the `href` would obviously bypass that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy way to set `IsRemote` default value.

```
public bool IsRemote { get; set; } = true;
```

This tag `asp-page` will link to Page `/JobPosts/Index.csthml` directly,

```
https://localhost:44391/JobPosts?cityId=2265885

= https://localhost:44391/JobPosts/Index?cityId=2265885
```

If you are looking forward the URL `https://localhost:44391/jobs?cityId=2265885`
you could try this a tag to request.

```
<a href="/cities/@Model.CityId/jobs">Go to JobPosts</a>
```

———————————————————————————————

Using a middleware to handle `/remote-jobs`

```
        app.Run(next => async context =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Path == "/remote-jobs")
            {
                return View with default IsRemote 
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Michelle for taking the time to answer, unfortunately this does not address any of my questions. Regarding the default value - I don't want it to be true for all routes, I want to define the default only for the `/remote-jobs` route - which is something that is possible using ASP.NET's classic routing system.

Comment: As for the URL suggestion - that's hardcoding. While you might get away with it in some cases, it's something I would like to avoid. Besides that, it's really not an option in my case. The site is multi language, so the route would actually be `/cities/@Model.CityId/jobs` or `{cultureId}/cities/@Model.CityId/jobs` based on context information. It is the job of the routing service to make this decision and come up with the URL, it would be crazy for each URL in the app to have an if/else and keep hardcoding hrefs based on available parameters.

Comment: The part with the `{cultureId}` works just fine through route conventions, but hardcoding the `href` as suggested would obviously bypass the routing mechanisms and so it would no longer work.

Comment: Hi, Marius, sorry for the immature answer and learn a lot from your comments. About the attribute routing, you might check this article https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/339/optional-parameters-in-razor-pages-routing

Comment: No worries, your effort and time is appreciated. Regarding the link you provided, it's more about optional parameters, I've got a few routes like that and they work just fine. What I need is being able to control which route is used for a given page - either by making a smart detection based on the provided parameters or based on route names. See here for classic routing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Notice how you can specify 3 things: name, pattern, defaults (which are not part of the pattern).

Comment: `if (context.Request.Path == "/remote-jobs")` - this might work, but only if I do Regex pattern matching. My url can also look like `/fr/remote-jobs/` and it's still the same route.

Comment: if (context.Request.Path.Contains( "/remote-jobs"))  could fix

Comment: As you mentioned, the classic  mvc  routing can use Conventional Routing  and Attribute Routing. I'm familiar with MVC routing, but not RazorPage routing.

Comment: Yeah, same here. I guess if I don't find an answer here I will move it to GitHub, maybe it's really a missing feature.